# How can I get the length of string for a page of screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, text

Now, I'm trying to create a novel(boot) text reader by C# WPF.

I am facing on a problem.
I don't know how can I split a string(from a text file) as a page of screen. ( like a book page )
(a page of screen is implmented by a label UI control. )
Because the string has 'New Line \n' & 'Tab' character.
So I cannot count how many characters can be inserted into a label(a page of screen).
label.TextLength returns the numbers of characters which can insert into the label.
But, if the string has '\n', it makes a lot of blanks.

So I hope to know how can I count the length of string which can inserted into a label with '\n'.
Or, Please guide me how can I create this program easily by using another UI controls.

< Additional info >

Thanks for your opinion. I added how I use label control.
In default label UI control changed it's size by the string which is inserted the label.
However, In this program, I will fix the label control size. It's size will be fit in Form size.

So, I should know the width & height(lines) of the label.
Or I hope to know controls or libraries for my program.(Unfortunately, I can't found it yet.)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to use a TextBlock control with TextWrapping="True"?

Comment: I will try TextBlock. But i'm not sure just a page of string.. because it's depends on many things. I hope to return from UI about how long string is in this UI. So I should start next page from xxx.

Comment: Well, it depends on screen-size, font-family, font-size etc. Haven't you seen, the flowdocument? Take a look at it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909(v=vs.100).aspx Another useful link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31834/FlowDocument-pagination-with-repeating-page-header

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
I've found these things!
It is as same with what I want to make!

Comment: You are Welcome! ;)

Comment: Please do not roll back the edits of experienced users here, unless you happen to _know_ that an edit is incorrect. Here, we don't add [solved] to titles - we use tick marks adjacent to the most helpful answer below. If the answer from user12572 is correct, please tick his/her tick mark, so it turns green. If not, please add a self-answer and tick that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlowDocument is the solution what I want!
Thank you to let me know that thing. - cicciorocca!!

Answer (score 0):

Your label can have `AutoSize=true` and `MaximumSize=new Size(maximumPageWidth, 0);`
This way your label will automatically word wrap when **maximum width** is reached. Every line will only increase the height of label.

Then you will need to add your text to this label line by line. Every time you add a line to this label, check if *maximumPageHeight* is reached or not.

If **maximum height** is reached then that's where your page ends. After this you need to add your next line to new page.

**Edit:** Above solution will work if you use System.Windows.Forms.Label

Comment: Question is about WPF